# How to change the Action View for an ActionBar's menu item with Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-actionbar, xamarin.android

I have a menu item with an icon in an `ActionBar` which I would like to change as a `ProgressBar` when the user click on it, run a task, and then change it back to an icon.
Below is the code I have, but nothing happens when the menu item is clicked.

The activity: ImportReferenceView.cs

```
public class ImportReferenceView : MvxActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ImportReferenceView);
        ActionBar.SetDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    }

    public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(Android.Views.IMenu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.import_actions, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(Android.Views.IMenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
            case Resource.Id.action_import:
                item.SetActionView(Resource.Layout.progressbar);
                item.ExpandActionView();
                var vm = ((ImportReferenceViewModel)ViewModel);
                Task task = Task.Run(() =>    vm.ImportCommand.Execute(vm.SelectedTableReferences));
                Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { task });
                item.CollapseActionView();
                item.SetActionView(null);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The menu actions: import_actions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item
      android:id="@+id/action_import"
      android:showAsAction="always"
      android:icon="@drawable/action_down"
      android:title="Refresh"/>
</menu>
```

The progressbar view: progressbar.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I am trying to achieve with Xamarin something like the one described in the Action Bar/Action View section of this [article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html#actionbar_actionview)

Any help or suggestion will be really appreciated

Comment: did you see `task.execute("test").get();` int the sample? no? so why you are using `Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { task });`? You are blocking the main thread in OnOptionsItemSelected ... do not expect to system redraw the UI ....

Comment: @selvin no I haven't, If you have some code, please share.

Comment: "With normal C#" I would use `Task.ContinueWith` with some UI Context/Dispatcher ... I will not write the code ... try to understand Task or AsyncTask, what is a main thread and other stuff first

Comment: I am looking for a clear and practical solution, And I don't see what using `Task.ContinueWith` will bring beside changing the structure of the code  since `Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { task });` is also "normal C#". FYI I played with Threads and Task for a couple of time. So if you haven't a clear explanation, or something to show, as recommended on Stackoverflow, then Thank you.

Comment: if you do not see the differences between `task.ContinueWith` and `Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { task });` I will not discuss with you ... it would be waste of my time... also you have the *clear and practical solution* in my second comment: *use Task.ContinueWith with some UI Context*

Comment: ok, good bye then. But if you ever have a solution, do not hesitate to share :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81508/discussion-between-godidier-and-selvin).

Comment: http://ideone.com/ntJ4IN of course touching UI from different thread will cause exception ... so you need to find out *with some UI Context*

Comment: It's more clear after you edited your first comment. I think I should use Task.Run() with a Dispatcher to avoid blocking the UI thread...  nothing todo with Task.ContinueWith VS Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { task }); I guess... Thank you very much @Selvin

Comment: NO!!! .... then the task will be runned on UI thread .... use task + CW + UI SynchronizationContext/TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()) because task should be run on background thread and continueWith part back on UI!  *FYI I played with Threads and Task for a couple of time.* it implicates that your code would be scary :)

Comment: I love horror movies too... ok thx

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I do it:

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
{
    MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.home_menu, menu);

    _refreshWrapper = new RefreshActionButtonWrapper(menu);
    var set = this.CreateBindingSet<HomeView, HomeViewModel>();
    set.Bind(_refreshWrapper).For("IsBusy").To(vm => vm.MyService.IsBusy);
    set.Apply();

    return true;
}
```

I use MvvmCross Data Binding to bind an *IsBusy* property to a wrapper class. You don't have to do that. You can set the *IsBusy* property directly (see example below).

```
public class RefreshActionButtonWrapper
{
    private readonly IMenu _optionsMenu;

    public RefreshActionButtonWrapper(IMenu optionsMenu)
    {
        _optionsMenu = optionsMenu;
    }

    private bool _isBusy;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return _isBusy; }
        set
        {
            _isBusy = value;

            var dispatcher = MvxMainThreadDispatcher.Instance;
            dispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction(() => SetRefreshActionButtonState(_isBusy));
        }
    }

    public void SetRefreshActionButtonState(bool refreshing)
    {
        if (_optionsMenu == null) return;
        var refreshItem = _optionsMenu.FindItem(Resource.Id.refresh_action);
        if (refreshing)
        {
            refreshItem.SetActionView(Resource.Layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);
        }
        else
        {
            refreshItem.SetActionView(null);
        }
    }
}
```

The trick is to change the action view on the Main thread. MvvmCross provides a method to invoke a request on the main thread:

```
var dispatcher = MvxMainThreadDispatcher.Instance;
dispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction(() => SetRefreshActionButtonState(_isBusy));
```

Then you can do something like this. Use *await* to wait for your import function to complete. I like to wrap IsBusy status in try/finally, to make sure that the IsBusy is always set to false, even on exceptions.

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(Android.Views.IMenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.ItemId)
    {
        case Resource.Id.action_import:
            try
            {
                _refreshWrapper.IsBusy = true;
                var vm = ((ImportReferenceViewModel)ViewModel);
                await Task.Run(() => vm.ImportCommand.Execute(vm.SelectedTableReferences));             
            }
            finally 
            {
                _refreshWrapper.IsBusy = false;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

> BTW: If you derive your view from *MvxActivity<ImportReferenceViewModel>* you will have a strongly typed *ViewModel* property and won't have to cast it.